# Populating a table with images based on an array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I am trying to populate an existing table of images by replacing the stock images with book cover images. I have an array of ISBN numbers which I want to concatenate to a URL that gets each image, and then display them in the table.

The table looks like this (4 rows, 5 columns):

```
<center><table id="booktable" width="850" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="6"><tbody align="center">
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <!-- "http://i.imgur.com/vaFKJ.png" -->
        <tr><td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vaFKJ.png" width="170" height="230" title="date"></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vaFKJ.png" width="170" height="230" title="date"></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vaFKJ.png" width="170" height="230" title="date"></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vaFKJ.png" width="170" height="230" title="date"></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vaFKJ.png" width="170" height="230" title="date"></td></tr>
```

And here I define my array of ISBN numbers. I want to replace the the URL in all 20 image tags with urls including each of the 20 ISBN numbers.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
        var isbns = ["0525953485", "1439102767", "0307588386", "0316097519", "0307273571", "0399161775", "0399160752", "0765323974", "0770437850", "0553801473", "1414319703", "0399158820", "0062231707", "0441020011", "0345523504", "0765325950", "1451647034", "0812993802", "0312591837", "039915812X"];
        for(var i=0; i<isbns.length; i++) {
            .html("<img src='http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/'+ isbns[i] + '-M.jpg' width="170" height="230" title="date">"
            }    
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var isbns = ["0525953485", "1439102767", "0307588386", "0316097519", "0307273571", "0399161775", "0399160752", "0765323974", "0770437850", "0553801473", "1414319703", "0399158820", "0062231707", "0441020011", "0345523504", "0765325950", "1451647034", "0812993802", "0312591837", "039915812X"];

        $.each(isbns, function(i, v){
            $('<img src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/'+ v + '-M.jpg" width="170" height="230" title="date">').appendTo('body')
        });
    });
</script>
```